# Mangata parachain can not produce blocks on rococo

Tags: relay-chain, rococo

Mangata stopped producing blocks in Rococo. We have not done anything in this environment for a while.

Every time the collator starts producing blocks, It prints the following entry log,

```
2024-02-20 08:31:06 [Relaychain] Collation wasn't advertised to any validator. candidate_hash=0x77b0ef2711e62e9030aaeba5ada90c315c84052e287a5ecd12591eae27004460 pov_hash=0x44fdf1ed92f999cf5e3867dba51f275133dbbacc66aa6f8013c835594c0f6eb3 traceID=159096826336840247337885360921611144241
```

Raw logs can be found here:
https://pastebin.com/Fk7EYHna

Mangata-version: 3,200

MangataRelease version: v0.33.0

Polkadot-SDK version: 1.0.1

Last block: 142 hr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason you had multiple cores assigned to your Parachain. Did you maybe buyed a core for your chain on the broker chain?

It is fixed now, I have removed the extra core. We are working on fixing this on the relay chain side, to support multiple cores per parachain.

Comment: Im not aware we did so, but will share with the team!

Comment: hey @bkchr,
I got a confirmation from a team member that maybe caused this, It's sad that we messed up and spent time on both sides, but its great that we found this on rococo instead of kusama!